# FineUploader scale thumbnails by one dimension (i.e. maxHeight or maxWidth rather than maxSize)

Tags: fine-uploader

The library takes a `maxSize` parameter for scaling, which applies to the longest of both dimensions. It seems that the work-around solution to scale by one dimension would be to manually run `scaleImage()` in an `onSubmitted` callback by calculating what the `maxSize` should be based on the original image size to get a result with the desired height or width, but this has its own hurdles:

It makes sense that using `addFiles()` inside of a `onSubmitted` callback would trigger another `onSubmitted` event; but if I use `addFiles()` to add the thumbnail, the thumbnail shows up in the UI list, and this triggers another `onSubmitted` causing another thumbnail to be generated, which keeps going in a loop.

I need to generate a thumbnail retrained by (a maxHeight of 240 pixels and a maxWidth of 320 pixels) and upload the thumbnail to a separate S3 bucket when `uploadStoredFiles()` is called, without triggering another `onSubmitted` event and without showing the thumbnail as a "duplicate" entry in the UI file list. What is the best way to do this in Fine-Uploader?

---

Some sample code:

```
          function makeThumbnail() {
            // FIXME to avoid duplicate, put this in the compression success
            var thumbnailPromise = uploader.scaleImage(id, {
              maxSize: 123,
              quality: 45,
              customResizer: !qq.ios() && function (resizeInfo) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                  pica.resizeCanvas(resizeInfo.sourceCanvas, resizeInfo.targetCanvas, {}, resolve)
                });
              }
            });
            thumbnailPromise.then(
                function (blob) {
                  console.log(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                  uploader.addFiles(blob);
                },
                function (err) {
                }
            );
          }
```

Comment: Are you submitting a new `File` or `Blob` to `addFiles` when you generate this "thumbnail"?

Comment: It comes from `scaleImage`'s Promise, which is a blob if I'm not mistaken. I've updated the question with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you pass a scaled `Blob` into `addFiles`, simply add a custom property to the `Blob` object, something like `blob.myScaledImage = true`. Then, when handling an `onSubmitted` callback, retrieve the associated `Blob` using the [`getFile` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getFile). If the `Blob` contains your custom property, don't re-scale it.

Comment: This `blob.myScaledImage = true` worked, thanks. I'm sorry for asking a multi-part question in one post, but it still shows up as a duplicate entry in the UI (one for the original image and one for the thumbnail), and I'm hoping to hear your word on how one should go about implementing a maxHeight and maxWidth functionality. If I should make a separate post for these questions, then I'll go ahead and mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply cancel whichever one you no longer need?

Comment: I need both the original image and its thumbnail to be uploaded

Comment: I found a hacky way to hide the duplicate entry, but hoping there's a better solution: `if (inputImage.isThumbnail == true) {$('li[qq-file-id="'+id+'"]').hide(); return;}`. At this point, this all seems do-able albeit hacky, I just have to think of some formula to calculate what the `maxSize` should be based on the maxHeight and maxWidth that I want.